# Is there a way to output variables as Java sees them so I can isolate methods for testing or asking for assistance?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and find myself sending methods around while asking for help but my problem is I have many methods and the data is modified at each method.  I often have to send large files when only one area is relevant(it makes my SO questions excessively long as well).

But for some of the stuff I do, I can't get the right data format to be outputted as string that I can input later. For example, if I add data to a list of Points(like this, `(new Point(0, 0));`) then when I output the results I get something like this(with sample data):

`[java.awt.Point[x=970,y=10], java.awt.Point[x=65,y=10], java.awt.Point[x=729,y=10]`

I get errors when I assign this to a variable and send it to my method I want to test/show.  I basically have two goals:

1. If I want help on a single method(thats part of a much larger class), I want to be able to send the least amount of code to the person helping me(ideally just the method itself and the inputs..which I'm unable to capture exactly right now).
2. When I test my code, I would like a way to isolate a method so I don't have to run a large file when all I can about is improving one method.

I am pretty sure I'm not the first person to come across this problem, How can I approach this?

UPDATE: Here's an example,

```
double[] data = new double[] {.05, .02, -.03, .04, .01}; 
System.out.println(data); //output is: [D@13fcf0ce
```

If I make a new variable of this and send it to a method I get errors.  I have 30 methods in a class. I want to have a friend help me with one. I'm to avoid sending 29 methods that are irrelevant to the person. So I need a way to capture the data, but printout doesn't seem to capture it in a way I can send to methods.

Comment: I don't understand the question: if your goal is to show the data being used, what's wrong with what you're showing? That's the data. If you're testing a single method, use a unit test (like via JUnit, TestNG, easyb, whatever), set up the data for the method, and test it.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry for not explaining it correctly.  I updated the question to show a specific case I'm getting this problem in(but it happens in other areas as well).

Comment: Moved to an answer for space, although it's more of an extended comment. It's still not entirely clear to me what problem you're trying to solve that isn't already solved. Creating a variable with data is really easy--just create a variable with data.

Comment: I updated the question with a simpler output, but I think your answer  got my problem right.  I have 30 methods in a class. I want to have  a friend help me with one. I'm to avoid sending 29 methods that are irrelevant to the person. So I need a way to capture the data, but printout doesn't seem to capture it in a way I can send to methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java outputs variables in a way that is human-readable (although it depends on the object's `toString` method). The output of `toString` is (unsurprisingly) a `String`. Unless you have a parsing mechanism to turn a string back into the original object, it's a one-way operation.

There should be no need to turn it back into the original object, however. If you're trying to isolate a function and sample data, the easiest thing to do is encapsulate it in a test and some data--there are many different ways to do this and communicate it to someone else.

I'm still unclear on your usecase, however. If it's an SO question, all you should need to do is show the code in question, provide a minimal amount of data that shows the problem, and you're done. This could be done in a self-contained example where you simple create the data in code, as a unit test, or by showing the string output as you've already done.

If you're trying to communicate the issue to a tech support tier, then the *best* mechanism depends entirely on what they're equipped to handle--they'll tell you if you didn't do it right, believe me.

Comment: I think you understand my problem exactly(its with the one way conversation to string). Idealy I just want to send a single method to someone with the data that goes in, but because of the one way string conversation, I'm forced to send a 1,000 line file in which only 10 lines of a specific method are relevant.   I don't know how to encapsulate it in a test, but as per your answer seems like the way to go, I'll look it up.

Comment: @learningJava Who cares about the irrelevant part? But it's always going to be pretty specific to what you're actually trying to communicate, what information is actually required to make sense of a problem (you may not need any data to describe the problem, you may only need a tiny subset of data, etc.), and what mechanisms are supported to load data. Maybe a data file makes more sense than code. Maybe a file of serialized object(s). Impossible to generalize this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Debuggers and step over your code. You can 'watch' variables so that you can get their actual value, rather than their `toString` representation. Debuggers are usually part and parcel with all the major IDE's such as Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ.

As to your questions about isolation and testing, this is much more of a design problem. Ideally your methods should be self contained, reducing coupling. What you could do is to learn to break down your problem into smaller chunks and until it can't be broken down further. Once you do this, you start building methods which tackle each part of the problem seperately.

Once you have your method, you test it on its own (thus reducing the amount of things which can go wrong, as opposed to testing tons of code at once). If you are satisfied, you integrate  the method with your code and test again. If something then goes wrong, you will know that your last module is the problem since it broke your system. You can get some more information about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).

Comment: I have it setup like this, my methods area all isolated and data comes in and data goes out.  The problem is I need to run the entire program to get the data to go into a method. I'm trying to figure a way where I can just create a variable with the data I expect to go in and then only run that single method to test.

Comment: @learningJava: This seems to be a rather specific problem so we won't be able to provide much help. What you can do is to extract that method in a seperate class, run your code to just before the method gets called and save the data to a file. Then, just run the method you are talking about on its own. While you are there you can also check to make sure that the data being given to the method is what you actually expect.

Comment: Thats a good idea, I'll try saving it a class. So far I have just outputted it to string and it looked different for some stuff..maybe saving it a file will have different results(which I can in turn use to create a variable with the inputs for a specific method).